# Удалить и заменить значения матрицы в модуле Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, модули

Мне нужно в `module_1` сделать функцию, которая удаляет в матрице, находящейся в файле, 4 последних строки, при этом заменив значение всех элементов на ноль.

Я могу сделать это всё по отдельности, но в одном `module_1` не получается. Код:

```
import csv
from matplotlib.pyplot import matshow, show
from module_1 import task_1
from module_2 import task_2
from module_3 import task_3
def read(csvfile):
    with open(csvfile, 'r') as file:
        r = list(csv.reader(file))
    for x in range(len(r)):
        for y in range(len(r[x])):
            r[x][y] = int(r[x][y])
    return r
def write(matrix, name = "result.csv"):
    with open(name, 'w') as file:
        for x in range(len(matrix)):
            for y in range(len(matrix[x])):
                if y == len(matrix[x]) - 1:
                    file.write(str(matrix[x][y]) + "\n")
                else:
                    file.write(str(matrix[x][y]) + " ")
t1 = task_1(read("tekst.csv"))
for x in range(len(t1)):
    print(t1, end='\n')
print('\n')
t2 = task_2(read("tekst.csv"))
for x in range(len(t2)):
    for y in range(len(t2[x])):
        print(t2[x][y], end=' ')
    print()
t3 = task_3(read("tekst.csv"))
for x in range(len(t3)):
    print(t3)
write(t2)
matshow(t2)
show()
```

Вот module_1,

```
def task_1(m): 
    d = []
    for i in range(len(m)):
        d.append([0]*len(m[i]))
    return d[:-4]
```

Если я использую этот код, получается такой вывод :

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

А нужно:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Входные данные в файле tekst.csv

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1
2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2
1,3,5,7,9,7,5,3
3,1,5,3,2,6,5,7
1,7,5,9,7,3,1,5
2,6,3,5,1,7,3,2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
def task_1(m):
    d = []
    for i in range(len(m[:-4])):
        d.append([0]*len(m[i]))
    return d
```

---

вы так печатаете, попробуйте так:

```
...

t1 = task_1(read("tekst.csv"))

for x in range(len(t1)):
    print(t1[x], end='\n')     #  t1[x] !!!
print('\n')

...
```

Comment: Да, но почему то вывод вот такой:


`[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
`
Он создаёт 4 матрицы, хотя и редактированные как надо)

Comment: Возможно ошибка кроется в основном коде, а не в модуле1, не могу понять

Comment: @Александр чтобы получать быстрые и правильные ответы, вы должны: 1. показать пример входных данных; 2. действия, которые вы производите с этими данными; 3. результат, который вы получаете после этих действий; 4, результат, который вы хотите получить.

Comment: Переделал вопрос под ваш способ и добавил желаемый результат

Comment: @Александр вы не показали пример входных данных

Comment: Забыл,  добавил в вопрос

Comment: @Александр  я отметил строку, которую вам надо исправить

Comment: Спасибо получилось, не знаю зачем я избавился от `[x]` , даже не заметил